# How to add a 'Confirm Email Address' to an event registration form

Tags: civievent, registration

I want to add a 'Confirm Email' field in an event's registration form, that is not saved as an extra field, but just acts as a validation function to the event's form submission.

Aside from writing custom JavaScript to do this as a hook, is there an easy way in CiviEvent?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re on Drupal create your event registration with webform_civicrm module and you can do just that

Here’s an example:
[image]